# Copying a MySQL database over HTTP

Tags: php, mysql, dump

I have 2 servers. On #1 remote DB access is disabled. Database is huge (~1GB) so there is no possible to dump it with phpMyAdmin as it crashes and hangs the connection. I have no SSH access. I need to copy entire DB to #2 (where I can set up virtually everything).

My idea is to use some kind of HTTP access layer over #1.

For example simple PHP script that accepts query as an _GET/_POST argument and returns result as HTTP body.

On #2 (or my desktop) I could set up some kind of server application that would ask sequentially for every row in every table, even one at the time.

And my question is: do you know some ready-to-use app with such a flow?

BTW: #1 is PHP only, #2 can be PHP, Python etc

I can't run anything on #1, all fopen, curl, sockets, system etc are disabled. I can only access DB from PHP, no remote connections allowed

Comment: Is your MySQL public or accessible in any possible way remotely?

Comment: get ssh, http is not designed for this and you would have to code a lot of control on top of it where existing protocols exist (having rsync or openvpn might help without full ssh access). Also you might try serverfault.

Comment: while it makes for an interesting question, I must ask why you don't just ask your sysadmin to migrate the data for you? are you trying to gather data from a source to which you are not supposed to be accessing in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

long time ago I used [Sypex Dumper](http://sypex.net/en/products/dumper/downloads/) for this, just left open browser for the night and next morning whle db dump was available on ftp

Answer (score 1):

Can you connect to a remote MySQL server from PHP on Server #1?

I know you said "no remote connections allowed", but you haven't specifically mentioned this scenario.

If this is possible, you could SELECT from your old database and directly INSERT to MySQL running on Server #2.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is available on the server #1.

Assuming you can run only php you still might be able to

- run [scp from php](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/function.ssh2-scp-send.php) and connect to server #2, send files like that
- maybe you can use php to run local commands on server #1? in that case something like running [rsync through php](http://www.ajaxapp.com/2008/05/21/php-rsync-mysql-building-your-own-datafile-remote-syncing-app/) from server #1 can work

Comment: I can't run anything on #1, all fopen, curl, sockets, system etc are disabled. I can only access DB from PHP, no remote connections allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you should contact the owner of the host and ask if you can get your data out somehow. It is a bit too stupid that you should stream your entire database and reinsert it on the new machine. It will eat a lot of resources on the php server you get the data from. (And if the hosting provider already is that restrictive, you might have a limit to how much sql operations you are allowed in a time span as well)

Though if you is forced to do it, you could do a select * from table and for each row convert it to a json object that you echo on the line. This you can store to disk on your end and use to insert it afterward.

Comment: would work, but terribly slow/painful. agree that contacting the admin would be the best route to get the data.

Comment: Hosting provider is totally unavailable -- he does not respond messages, mails, phone calls for over three years. However server and domain continues to work, pretty amazing. And I think that this is the only option -- I'm only asking if there is a software I can use before I start to write my own.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you can access both servers using FTP.

How do you get your php files on it otherwise.

Perhaps you can just copy the mysql database if you can access it using FTP.

Works not in all cases check out: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html for more info.

Or you can try the options found on this link:

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

Don't now how your php is setup though as I can imagine it can take some time to process the entire database.

max execution time setting etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is the replication option, if at least one of the hosts is reachable remotely via TCP. It would be slow to synch a virgin DB this way, but it would have the advantage of preserving all the table metadata that you would otherwise lose by doing select/insert sequences. More details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you managed to get into this situation. The hosting provider is clearly being unreasonable, and you should contact them. You should also stop using their services as soon as possible (although this sounds like what you're trying to do anyway).

Unfortunately PHPMyAdmin is not suitable for database operations which are critical for data as it's got too many bugs and limitations - you certainly shouldn't rely on it to dump or restore.

mysqldump is the only way to RELIABLY dump a database and bring it back and have a good chance for the data to be complete and correct. If you cannot run it (locally or remotely), I'm afraid all bets are off.